# Can I modify an MVC route outside of Global.asax?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Is it possible to modify the the routes (and thus the RouteTable) outside of the global.asax file, maybe in a controller?  Is this even advisable?

My reason for asking has to do with IIS 6 and Integrated Mode not allowing for Request context calls.  I'm implementing internationalization for a site and keeping track of the culture in the URL.  The culture is originally read from a .config file and loaded as a route default.  This file read is what ends up throwing the error (another few steps up the stack).  I based this off the method described [here](http://adamyan.blogspot.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the routing table pretty much anywhere like so System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes, have tested this from a controller and it worked fine.